# I'm over-querying my MySql database. Another way to retrieve many data?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this Table structure, and I'm retrieving data with many querys.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1Zjm.png

Here's how I'm querying the DB.

```
$siteurl = mysql_query("SELECT option_value FROM main_conf WHERE option_name = 'siteurl' ");
$_siteurl = mysql_result($siteurl,0);


$staticurl = mysql_query("SELECT option_value FROM main_conf WHERE option_name = 'staticurl' ");
$staticurl = mysql_result($staticurl,0);


$sitetitle = mysql_query("SELECT option_value FROM main_conf WHERE option_name = 'sitetitle' ");
$_sitetitle = mysql_result($sitetitle,0);


$sitesubtitle = mysql_query("SELECT option_value FROM main_conf WHERE option_name = 'sitesubtitle' ");
$_sitesubtitle = mysql_result($sitesubtitle,0);

$logofile = mysql_query("SELECT option_value FROM main_conf WHERE option_name = 'logofile' ");
$_logofile = mysql_result($logofile,0);

$cat1 = mysql_query("SELECT option_value FROM main_conf WHERE option_name = 'cat1' ");
$_cat1 = mysql_result($cat1,0);

$cat2 = mysql_query("SELECT option_value FROM main_conf WHERE option_name = 'cat2' ");
$_cat2 = mysql_result($cat2,0);

echo $_siteurl;

echo $_staticurl;

echo $_sitetitle;

echo $_sitesubtitle;

echo $_logofile;

echo $_cat1;

echo $_cat2;
```

Is there another way to do that?.

Thanks!

Comment: heard of the magical `OR` ? or even `IN`

Comment: Fetch as much as you need to with `OR` statements and iterate over the data.

Comment: Any example code please. I'm not lazy, but even I have no idea how to search correctly.

Comment: No, no, no. Not pngs. sqlfiddles... maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably find it easiest to fetch the results in one row.  You can do this in SQL using aggregation:

```
SELECT max(case when option_name = 'siteurl' then option_value end) as siteurl,
       max(case when option_name = 'sitetitle' then option_value end) as sitetitle,
       max(case when option_name = 'sitesubtitle' then option_value end) as sitesubtitle,
       max(case when option_name = 'logofile' then option_value end) as logofile,
       max(case when option_name = 'cat1' then option_value end) as cat1,
       max(case when option_name = 'cat2' then option_value end) as cat2
FROM main_conf
WHERE option_name in ('siteurl', 'sitetitle', 'sitesubtitle', 'logofile', 'cat1', 'cat2');
```

The results will be one row with six columns, one for each value.

Comment: Hello Gordon,

How can I put this work together in these scenario?

" Hi, my name url is <?php echo $siteurl;> and here's my logo <img src="<?php echo $logofile; ?>" /> "

Many thanks for your reply... I really appreciate it.

Comment: @eplazai . . . This is the SQL part of the solution.  You need to manage the php code to read the six option values.  By the way, you should not use the "mysql_" interface, it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon, I've made the homework. :D

..this is the full code.

```
<?php

SELECT max(case when option_name = 'siteurl' then option_value end) as siteurl,
       max(case when option_name = 'sitetitle' then option_value end) as sitetitle,
       max(case when option_name = 'sitesubtitle' then option_value end) as sitesubtitle,
       max(case when option_name = 'logofile' then option_value end) as logofile,
       max(case when option_name = 'cat1' then option_value end) as cat1,
       max(case when option_name = 'cat2' then option_value end) as cat2
FROM main_conf
WHERE option_name in ('siteurl', 'sitetitle', 'sitesubtitle', 'logofile', 'cat1',    'cat2');

//this is my homework, the php part of the problem

$siteurl = mysql_result($query_from_main_conf, 0, 0);
$staticurl = mysql_result($query_from_main_conf, 0, 1);
$sitetitle = mysql_result($query_from_main_conf, 0, 2);
$sitesubtitle = mysql_result($query_from_main_conf, 0, 3);
$logofile = mysql_result($query_from_main_conf, 0, 4);
$cat1 = mysql_result($query_from_main_conf, 0, 5);
$cat2 = mysql_result($query_from_main_conf, 0, 6);

?>
```

Then, I retrieved the content just using ECHOs.

i.e.

```
<?php echo $cat1; ?>
```

THANKS!!